# Объединение баз Firebird

Tags: база-данных, firebird

Есть 3 одинаковых базы с разными данными, велись локально на трех клиентских ПК. Юзеры взрослели и вмести с ними тучнели базы, ходили в отпуска и при принятии временных обязанностей скакали между клиентскими местами, и захотелось им комфорта - с одного рабочего места видеть все изменения вносимые непосильным трудом в определенную базу.

и ...
и стала сеть
и был выделен ПК под db сервер
и ...

А как объединить данные из 2,3,etc... в одну общую базу? База в firebird, может есть howto?

Спасибо!

firebird, compare

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, есть три идентичные по структуре (таблицы и т.д) БД Firebird, но с разным наполнением. Объединить их простым Backup/Restore не получится по причине дублирования первичных ключей в соответствующих таблицах.

Самое простое это написать отдельную программку для переливки таблиц БД или использовать внешние таблицы-файлы. В первом случае в програмке по три раза вызывались бы запросы вида select * from table1 для исходной БД и insert для общей БД. Во втором -создаем внешнюю таблицу, аналогичную переносимой и далее select/insert from.

Но ... скорее всего во всех трёх БД:  1. есть некоторые таблицы "классификаторов" данные которых общие для всех БД или различаются только незначительно (их надо загрузить в первую очередь а различия добавить с новыми id)  2. "справочники", таблицы в которых содержится, скорее всего, только различные данные (например, клиенты, пользователи и т.д.).Такие таблицы загружаем во вторую очередь. И учитываем, что они (id)скорее всего зависят только от "классификаторов"  3. различные "связки" - загружаем  их в третью очередь.

По поводу id:  - Во всех таблицах общей БД необходимо создать новые поля id_old и id_dubl, в одно будем грузить старое значение id, а другое будет указывать на базовое значение, если строка это повтор (дубль).  - Все записи из трёх БД можно прогрузить с новыми id (сгенерённым по триггеру) и загрузкой старого id в поле id_old  - Заменить все "связи" на новые id. (на этом этапе БД уже рабочая, даже можно включить "ограничения")  - Заняться долгим процесов "чистки БД" от дубликатов. (Дубликат удаляется в три этапа: 1-в поле id_dubl ставится id той записи дублем которого он является, 2- все ссылки из других таблиц на этот id заменяются на значение id_dubl 3- дубликат можно удалить)

Comment: Можно без id_old и id_dubl обойтись. Просто поменять id сразу же. В первой базе id = id * 10, во второй id = (id * 10) + 1, в третьей id = (id * 10) + 2. Таким образом они станут уникальными по всему набору баз.

Answer (score 0):

> а как же сделать backup 2,3,etc баз и залить в одну ?

если у вас там хранятся данные которые будут друг друга перекрывать, то можно залить из backup в отдельную таблицу и апдейтить ту информацию которая новее.

P.S.: с firebird сталкивался очень редко, никогда она мне не нравилась :)